# Derivative Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I have two questions.

1. Give example a function $f$ and $g$ that defined on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists, but $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ does not exist.
2. Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$. Show that, if $a \geq 0$ then there exists $x_1, x_2, x_3 \in (a, b)$ such that $f'(x_1) = (b+a) \frac{f'(x_2)}{2x_2} = (b^2+ab+a^2) \frac{f'(x_3)}{3x_3^2}$
   (Hint: use Cauchy Mean Value Theorem).

I think for number 2, we need to construct two functions $f$ and $g$ (since Cauchy MVT needs two functions to work with), but I have no idea what they should be. Can someone give me some hints? Thanks.

Comment: For 1, consider the fact that 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x \sin(1/x) & x \neq 0\\
0 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
has a limit as $x \to 0$, but its derivative (which is defined on all non-zero $x$) has no limit as $x \to 0$.

Comment: So, what function $g$ should be?

Comment: Pick any continuously differentiable function for which $g(0)$ and $g'(0)$ are both non-zero

Comment: Okay, so can I pick $g(x) = x+1$, since $g$ is continuous and differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, $g(0)$ and $g'(0)$ are both non-zero ?

Comment: That's what I claim. You should confirm that this satisfies the requirement for the problem

Comment: Yes, I've checked and it satisfies the requirement. Thank you very much!

Comment: $$\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\left| x\right| }{x+1}=0$$ but $$\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\text{ sgn}(x)$$ fails to exist

Comment: Thank you @Raffaele !

Comment: For $1$, the easiest way to answer the question is to take non-differentiable functions.